# pattern between two strings in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string in following format:

In-product feedback from Vince (aaa@bbb.com)...In-product feedback from Corey Zimmerman Anderson (ccc@ddd.com)...In-product feedback from Andrea Ibarra (eee@fff.com)

I need to extract the email ID from above string. The "In-product feedback from " will be static and email IDs will always be inside parenthesis, but the name in between will vary.

Comment: Can you show your efforts, plus there are lots of questions on SO that show regex patterns for extracting email addresses from strings

Comment: So are you just trying to extract the text inside the parentheses?

Answer (score 3):

Since the text you have is pretty much static and names will likely not contain `()` you can use a non regex approach:

```
s = "In-product feedback from Vince (aaa@bbb.com)"
s_clean = s.rsplit('(')[1].strip(')')
print(s_clean)
# 'aaa@bbb.com'
```

Or use regex anyway:

```
import re

s = "In-product feedback from Vince (aaa@bbb.com)"
s_clean = re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', s)[0]
print(s_clean)
# 'aaa@bbb.com'
```

---

And with multiple occurrences, you'll get a list of all the emails:

```
s = "In-product feedback from Vince (aaa@bbb.com)...In-product feedback from Corey Zimmerman Anderson (ccc@ddd.com)...In-product feedback from Andrea Ibarra (eee@fff.com)"
s_clean = re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', s)
print(s_clean)
# ['aaa@bbb.com', 'ccc@ddd.com', 'eee@fff.com']
```

Comment: Yes, if you remove the `[0]`, you'll get a list of all occurrences with `s_clean = re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', s)`. See my update

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
import re
r = re.findall(r"\(([^)]+)\)", s)
print(r)
```

where s in your strings.

Comment: Hi UpmostScarab: I have multiple occurrence of the pattern in my string. Your code returns only the last occurrence. How can i modify it to return all occurrences ?

Comment: Thanks ... it did :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import re
str = 'In-product feedback from Vince (aaa@bbb.com)'
regex = '(In-product feedback from) ([a-zA-Z ]+) \(([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)\)'
phrase= re.match(regex, str)
print phrase.group(1) # In-product feedback from
print phrase.group(2) # Vince 
print phrase.group(3) # aaa@bbb.com
```